# Is it possible to create a multi-select enum in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model with an enum field, and currently documents can have any single value from the enum. I want documents to be allowed to have an array of values, but have mongoose enforce that all of the values are valid options that exist in the enum - is that possible?

Essentially I want the equivalent of a HTML `<select multiple>` element instead of a `<select>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can apply an `enum` to a path that's defined as an array of strings. Each value will be passed to the enum validator and will be checked to ensure they are contained within the enum list.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    //...
    pets: {type: [String], enum: ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Snake"]}
    //...
});

//... more code to register the model with mongoose
```

Assuming you have a multi-select in your HTML form with the name `pets`, you could populate the document from the form post, within your route, like this:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var user = new User();

//make sure a value was passed from the form
if (req.body.pets) {
    //If only one value is passed it won't be an array, so you need to create one
    user.pets = Array.isArray(req.body.pets) ? req.body.pets : [req.body.pets]; 
}
```

Comment: I am using this code to fetch the enum values: `UserSchema.path('pets').options.enum`

Comment: So the validation will work same as single value. `['a', 'b']` will be fail when compared with enum list `['a','c','d']` ?

Comment: Aamir, that's correct. The `enum` array indicates the list of allowed values for either an array or single value.

Answer (score 4):

For reference, on Mongoose version 4.11 the enum restriction on the previous accepted answer **does not work**, but the following **does work**:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  role: [ { type: String, enum: ["admin", "basic", "super"] } ]
  //...
})
```

Or, if you want/need to include things other than `type`:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  role: {
    type: [ { type: String, enum: ["admin", "basic", "super"] } ],
    required: true
  }
  //...
})
```